# A step up from perl?

Tags: perl

I am curious, if I am looking for something that is a "step up" from Perl is terms of difficulty. Where would I go?

Is python higher? Ruby? Java?

Am I getting warmer?

Would adding GUIs to my perl script be a higher level of difficulty?

I love Perl but I am looking to branch out a little bit and try other things.

Comment: The only step-up from Perl in terms of difficulty is trying to read Sanskrit after having a frontal lobotomy, and both eyes poked out with a sharp stick :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo What? Perl is hard? That's new.

Comment: What do you think might be useful to you in the near future ?

Comment: I found Prolog to be difficult. Go for a declarative language :)

Comment: @RomainHippeau Well I was thinking C++ but based of what I have read its still a little much.

Comment: Using Wx for GUI would sure add more difficulty.

Comment: Mastering any (practical) programming language is hard -- regardless of the choice of language.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't know C, learn C. Benefit: you can write extension to Perl making your Perl skill even more powerful. If you have already known C, learn Lisp or other functional programming language. Benefit: get into touch a totally different flavor of language, broaden your view.

Comment: I do not know C, is C harder than C++?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider a functional language like, say, Haskell.  I don't know that it's *harder* than Perl, but it's different enough that it should expand your ideas of what programming is about.

Comment: Is haskell "cross platform"? or is it mostly Linux / Unix?

Comment: I use both so it is not a big deal either way.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is a scripting language, Ruby, Python and PHP are scripting languages too. If it is a new challenge you are after try a common compiled language like any C derivative (C, C++, C#, Java).